# Find C++ platform target at compile time in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, target, platform

I am building my solution for x86 and x64 platforms.
Does Visual Studio have any target platform variables so I find which platform I am building for in compile time?

For example:

```
HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
#ifdef TARGET_X86
hinstLib = LoadLibrary("32lib.dll"); 
#endif

#ifdef TARGET_X64
hinstLib = LoadLibrary("64lib.dll"); 
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
     // Microsoft VC compiler
#    if defined(_WIN32)
#        if defined(_WIN64)
             // 64 bit windows
#        else
             // 32 bit windows
#        endif
#    endif
#endif
```

Note that _WIN32 **is** defined for 64 bit too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b0084kay.aspx

`_WIN64` or `_M_X64` should work.

So for your example:

```
HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
#ifdef _WIN64
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary("64lib.dll"); 
#else
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary("32lib.dll"); 
#endif
```